# Generate url with path twig function that doesn't meet the route requirements

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have fallowing Route defined:

```
@Route("/photo/edit/{id}", name="gallery_photo_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
```

Since I have to make an Ajax request I need to generate it and put in JS code.
For example

```
var $PhotoEditActionUrl = "{{ path("gallery_photo_edit", {id: ":id:"}) }}";
```

As you can see I want to assign id that is a string-placeholder since I don't know the id of photo user will be editing. Obvious problem is Route requirements does not allow that. Is there a walk around without removing requirements that serves as an additional security measurement?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to generate a route using JS, an existant bundle is useful, and hosted on github :

- **FOS JS Routing Bundle** :
  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

After install it, you can call it in JS via something like :

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10, foo: "bar" });
// will result in /foo/10/bar?foo=bar
```

Extract from this doc : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md